# Player Score for Android Java

Tags: java, android

I am on working android java for game scoring. My problem is that the score for player 1 doesn't display, but the score for player 2 does display. One other problem is that the score for player 1 is adding score for player 2.

Here is my code:

```
private static int player = 1;
int Pscore1;
int Pscore2;

String win;

if (dice1 == dice2)
            {

                text.setText("Player " + (new Integer(player)).toString() + " wins !");

                if (win == "Player " + (new Integer(player)).toString())
                {
                    Pscore1++;
                    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2);
                    result.setText("Player 1 Score :" + Pscore1 + " || Player 2 Score :" + Pscore2);
                }

                else 
                {
                    Pscore2++;
                    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2);
                    result.setText("Player 1 Score :" + Pscore1 + " || Player 2 Score :" + Pscore2);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `win.equals("Player" + new Integer(player).toString())` instead of `if (win == "Player " + (new Integer(player)).toString())`

Hope this helps.

Comment: `win.equals("Player" + new Integer(player).toString())` This checks if win equals "Player #"

Comment: Thanks..it was typo mistake.

Comment: No problem. Coding needs a sharp eye and you spotted his mistake when I couldn't. I spotted yours so that your answer wouldn't get downvotes ;)

Comment: sorry, your solution can't solve my problem. I don't understand about "Player #"

Comment: Player # is Player number.Example, Player 1 or Player 2.

Comment: sorry. nope.but know my application can run :)